# How to make a centered gallery layout with CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create an attractive layout for a series of equally-sized boxes.  The number of boxes will vary. The idea is to flow the boxes into rows and columns to fill up a container; container size varies with the size of the web browser's window.  Normally, you can do this easily with a `float: left;` for each of the boxes.  Here is the wrinkle: I would like to have the last row, if it is uneven, be centered.

Example: Thirteen boxes.  Three rows of four boxes, with the thirteenth box centered within the fourth row.

[image]

I'm almost positive this has leaped far out of the realm of CSS, even CSS3, but I was wondering if there were Javascript libraries or at least well-known algorithms for handling this kind of thing.  I have some very brute force ideas about it but my guess is that someone else has already done this in a more elegant fashion.

Even something like being able to pick out a given box's row and column would be a great start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `<img />` is right inside the `.row` , it seems pretty easy to do something like:

```
.row:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If not, you can still use `:last-child`, only like:

```
.row:last-child .box {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

About actually generating HTML code itself, you didn't provide enough information to adress that matter, but hovewer you do it, either by generating only `<img />` and wrapping every n-th of them in `.row` or by generating them inside `.box`, those styles are going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `flexbox` like so:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
</div>
```